# AChartEngine Doughnut chart margins

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I am charting using AChartEngine in a linearlayout.

I have been having problem setting Doughnut chart margins. I am using the following statement but the margins or the center is not changing. The chart is auto-sizing based on the layout dimensions. Can anyone please help?

mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 50, 20, 20});

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to play with the parameter to the method below. The original value is 1, so a lower value will make it smaller and a higher one bigger.

```
renderer.setScale(scale);
```

Don't forget to call repaint after this:

```
mChartView.repaint();
```

Comment: Excellent! Works awesome...I still don't have 15 reputation to vote UP! Thank you Dan....

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish the chart to autosize, then try specifying the layout size explicitly using the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes instead of just setting to `WRAP_CONTENT`. Also if there is a `ScrollView` in the layout's ancestor hierarchy, you'll have to call `renderer.setInScroll(true);`

Comment: The problem is even if I explicitly set the layout_width and layout_height, I am unable to control the actual size of doughnut (diameter). For example, in a LineChart, you can control the chart size with margins, but how do you do it with Doughnut chart?